# Oracle 10g Listener issues after IT changed computer domain name

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, listener

I need some help here.

We have Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 installed on a windows 2008R2 machine.

The issue is that our IT department changed the domain for that machine.
I tried editing our tnsnames.ora and listner.ora files and restarted the listener service.

I can connect to the database remotely using sqldeveloper, but if I try to connect through one our legacy apps that uses BDE I'm getting ORA-03114: not connected to ORACLE.

In addition to this when I try to do a imp command or try to sign in using the sqlplus command on the box I get the following error.

ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

So I believe I'm missing something a step here.  I've tried this as well
http://www.oralytics.com/2011/03/changing-domain-of-oracle-database.html
But I received a warning trying to drop the repo, and received an error trying to create it.

lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on 24-JAN-2018 10:48
:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                24-JAN-2018 10:39:51
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 8 min. 29 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.o
ra
Listener Log File         C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\log\listener.log

Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=MYCOMPUTERNAME.myNewDomain)(POR
T=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl.myNewDomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclXDB.myNewDomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl_XPT.myNewDomain" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

listner.ORA file

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYCOMPUTERNAME.myNewDomain)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

TNSNAMES.ora

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = MYCOMPUTERNAME.MYNEWDOMAIN)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Update:  Added my SQLNET.ORA file
    # sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
    # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = MYCOMPUTERNAME.MYCOMPUTERDOMAIN
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: A 15 years old Oracle version on a 10 years old operating system. You may consider an upgrade.

Comment: It's in the plans, but is not possible at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the entry in SQLNET.ora file of following parameter?

names.default_domain = world

If it doesn't contain your myNewDomain domain name then kindly modify it. I hope it will resolve your domain name misconfiguration. Or ask your system admin to check /etc/hosts file for domain name properly enter or not.

Comment: Thanks,  I have tried this and I still see the issue.  But based on what I'm reading this should work.